# Probability of non repeated value in a set of vectors (with integer values) for any number in the same vector position.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Suppose a set with $m$ vectors ($m$ finite) defined by $V_{i} = (x_{vi1},x_{vi2},\dots,x_{vin})$, with $i \in \left\{1, 2, \dots, m \right\}$ and $2 \leq n \leq p$, for a given $p \in \mathbb{Z}$

Also, consider that $x_{k} \in \mathbb{Z}$; $0 \leq x_{k} \leq l$ for a given $l \in \mathbb{Z}$; $\forall k \in \left\{1, 2, \dots, n \right\}$.

My question is: Is there a possibility to find a closed formula to calculate the probability that for all vectors $V_{i}, V_{j}, i\neq j$ there isn't any pair $x_{vik}, x_{vjk}$ such as $x_{vik} = x_{vjk}$.

To give a numerical example of the problem:

Suppose that we have $100$ vectors in which each entry is a number between $0$ and $300$ with $1000$ positions each.

$A = (a_1, a_2, \dots, a_{1000})$

$B = (b_1, b_2, \dots, b_{1000})$

$C = (c_1, c_2, \dots, c_{1000})$

$\vdots$ (more $97$ other vectors like this)

Is there any way to calculate the probability that $(a_1 \neq b_1) \wedge (a_1 \neq c_1) \wedge \dots \wedge (b_1\neq c_1) \wedge (b_1 \neq d_1) \wedge \dots \wedge (a_2 \neq b_2) \wedge \dots$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Think about the first coordinate of any vector. In the vector $v_1=(v^1_1,\cdots, v^1_n)$ you $l+1$ numbers to choose. Now, since $v^2_1\ne v^1_1$ you have $l$ numbers to choose the first coordinate of the vector $v_2=(v^2_1,\cdots, v^2_n).$ Finally, since $v^i_1\ne v^m_1$ (for all $i=1,\cdots, m-1)$ you have $l+1-m$ numbers to choose for the first coordinate of $v_m=(v^m_1,\cdots, v^m_n).$ So, we have that the number of possible ways to choose the first coordinate is $(l+1)^m$ and the number of favourable cases is $(l+1)\cdot l \cdots (l+1-m).$ That is, the probability that all vectors have different first coordinate is

$$\frac{(l+1)\cdot l \cdots (l+1-m)}{(l+1)^m}=\frac{l \cdots (l+1-m)}{(l+1)^{m-1}}=\frac{\displaystyle \frac{l!}{(l-m)!}}{(l+1)^{m-1}}.$$

Can you get the solution from this point?

Comment: You have $l+1$ ways to choose the first number. So, if the second is different, you can choose it between $l$ numbers. If the third is different from the first and the second you have $l-1$ ways to choose it, and so on. Consider $l=2.$ The first number can be $0,1,2.$ Once chosen one of them, say $0,$ you have to choose between $1,2.$ That is, you have two possibilities. Say, you choose $1.$ Finally, the third one must be $2.$ That is, $3\cdot 2 \cdot 1.$

Comment: You are right. Also, I got it from here because since they are independent for each coordinate. $P((a_1 \neq b_1) \wedge (a_2 \neq b_2) \dots )= P(a_1 \neq b_1) \cdot P((a_2 \neq b_2) \dots ) = \Bigg( \dfrac{\dfrac{l!}{(l-m)!}}{(l+1)^{m-1}} \Bigg) ^n$